# How to view special characters in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Sql 2005

I have a text column that has special characters stored e.g. CR, LF, but I don't know what they are. I would like to view these characters in management studio. Something like in Notepad ++ > Show Symbol > Show All Characters.

My Goal:
I am working on a data conversion from one database to another. When the data is converted and viewed in the native application it is displaying some funky characters like a pipe character. I would like to eliminate these characters during the conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're converting from one db to another, what you really need to do is to scrub the data so that what ends up in the second db contains only "valid" characters. Therefore, take advantage of the logic provided in [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=56713) to create your own scrubbing system which will remove the special characters as you transfer the data. Since this script uses the list of valid characters, you should be able to remove the special characters that are causing trouble without actually knowing what they are.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I guess my only concern would be for allowing CR LF characters in. I will look into it a bit more.